# Disable Validation rule in Salesforce1

Tags: salesforce1-app, validation

Is there a way through which I can disable a validation rule in Salesforce1 (User logging in from iPhone) but it should be activated while user logs in from laptop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't possible. One of the major benefits of [validation rules](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=fields_about_field_validation.htm&language=en_US) is that they run whenever those records are interacted with (except of course [Quick Create](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000IYRFAA4)...). Note from the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=fields_validation_considerations.htm&language=en_US):

> Validation rules verify that the data a user enters in a record meets
>   the standards you specify before the user can save the record.
>
> ...
>
> Validation rules apply to new and updated records for an object, even
>   if the fields referenced in the validation rule are not included in a
>   page layout or an API call.

Now, you could try to write a validation rule to check for Salesforce1 and skip it, but unfortunately that isn't possible. It isn't that easy to [detect if you are in Salesforce1](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/33514/605) under any circumstances, especially not in a validation rule.