# Can we diffentiate if a VF page is being opened on a Tablet or on a Phone device, while viewing the page in Salesforce1?

Tags: apex, visualforce, salesforce1-app, salesforce1-platform

Can we detect in Apex or Visualforce whether the page is being opened in on a Phone or a Tablet device?

I'm looking to render VF page conditionally if it is viewed on Tablet or if it is viewed on a Phone.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detect if Visualforce Page is in Salesforce1](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/33514/detect-if-visualforce-page-is-in-salesforce1)

Comment: hmmm.. I don't think so, I know we can detect if page is in SF1 as we can but wanted some solid in roads for an answer to see if we can detect if it is an iPad or an iPhone ...

Comment: Check the User-Agent into your apex page header Apexpages.currentPage().getHeaders().get('User-Agent'). I'm not too sure, but you can find a lot of info in there.

Answer (score 1):

We can do it by getting the user-agent:
Server End

```
String userAgent = System.currentPageReference().getHeaders().get('User-Agent');

if (userAgent.contains('iPhone')){
           // your code here
}
else if (userAgent.contains('iPad')){
         // your code here
}  //added comment to allow code formatting
```

Comment: Sure, if you're 100% certain that all your users are on Apple devices...