# How to remove custom image buttons from Salesforce1 page layouts

Tags: salesforce1-app, page-layout, salesforce1-platform

I have built some customized image buttons (formula fields) in Salesforce that work great on the desktop but do not work at all on Salesforce1 and are not necessary anyway.  Can certain fields be omitted from showing up on the Salesforce object page layout.  I haven't seen where I can hide these?

Answer (score 3):

This [idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000kxyTAAQ) is under product team review and would make it possible. You may want to upvote it. As a workaround, you can use [this](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/33514/detect-if-visualforce-page-is-in-salesforce1) approach to determine whether your page is rendering within Salesforce1 and do conditional processing as required.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have a different page layout for Salesforce1 and desktop. I'm afraid the only solution would be to change your customized image buttons so that they work as well as possible on both of them.