# Making visualforce aware if it is being viewed on Salesforce1

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app

I want my page to be aware if it is being viewed through the salesforce1 app or through a browser...

What is the best way to do this through visualforce markup?

Comment: Possible duplicate of this question: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/33514/detect-if-visualforce-page-is-in-salesforce1?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to extract required information from page header, accessed by PageReference.

For more details refer https://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/pages/Content/apex_system_pagereference.htm#RequestHeadersSection