# Lightning Experience gets 'stripped' when redirecting from Visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce, pagereference, redirect, lightning-experience

I`m struggling to fix an issue which arise with the new Salesforce Lightning Experience. So, I have a Visualforce page which is assigned to the Edit functionality of Accounts. In Salesforce Classic mode everything works perfectly good, but when I switch to the new Lightning Experience I get a strange behavior on redirect - the lightning is removed and I get redirected to the classic mode page. I hope to clarify things with the below screenshots.

First, I edit one of my accounts to go to my Visualforce page.

[image]

Second, I fill in the data in click save which should return me back to the account details page.

[image]

Unfortunately, the result is as folows:

[image]

I'm using `PageReference` object in my Apex controller for navigation, but from what I've red it is not working with the Lightning.

For example:

```
    PageReference pg = null;
    try{
        pg = stdController.save();  
    }catch(Exception ex){           
        Logger.Instance.LogException(ex, false);
    }

    return pg;
```

If anyone can give me directions, I would be very grateful!

**Solution**
I have managed to solve this issue by invoking the controller methods which handled the navigation as `<apex:actionFunction>`. Also I have added a 'lightning experience check' in my controller to be able to return `null` in the `PageReference` methods so that navigation is handled by the javascript. In the `complete` event of the actionFunction's I managed the navigation with the `sforce.one` object.

Comment: Hi Vortex, 
I am facing similar problem. I have used sforce.one in my javascript function to redirect. But how can we check for lightning experience at controller side?

Comment: Hi Santanu Halder. Check out this thread -> http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/33514/detect-if-visualforce-page-is-in-salesforce1