# How to detect if a user is in Salesforce1 vs Lightning Desktop

Tags: visualforce, lightning-experience

**Has anyone figured out a way to differentiate between Lightning Desktop and Salesforce1?**

There are mechanisms to detect if a user is using Lightning Desktop / Salesforce1 vs Salesforce Classic (Aloha). See [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/lex_dev_visualforce/lex_dev_visualforce_multipurpose_pages) for a Javascript solution.

I know officially ([same link - see 'Limitations of Detecting sforce.one'](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/lex_dev_visualforce/lex_dev_visualforce_multipurpose_pages)) there is no supported mechanism yet. I've also read about the Visualforce [workaround](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/33514/detect-if-visualforce-page-is-in-salesforce1) that is out at the moment.

I want to know specifically a front end way to tell the two interfaces apart.

Thanks
Nelson

Comment: does user-agent help here by any chance ?

Comment: Thanks I'm looking into it. I think there's a problem with certain devices that don't send a standard 'token' in the user agent so that we can easily tell what device it is. One I can think of is the Kindle Fire HDX. Here's a good resource pointing out common User Agent  strings for Tablets and Mobile : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Browser_detection_using_the_user_agent#Mobile.2C_Tablet_or_Desktop

Answer (score 11, accepted):

With **Spring 16 release**, we are getting new values added to the existing `$User.UITheme` Global variable and to the `UserInfo.getUiTheme()` method which will help us to identify the current user's UI mode.

here's the list of possible values

- Theme1 — Obsolete Salesforce theme
- Theme2 — Salesforce Classic 2005 user interface theme
- Theme3 — Salesforce Classic 2010 user interface theme
- Theme4d — Modern “Lightning Experience” Salesforce theme
- Theme4t — Salesforce1 mobile Salesforce theme
- PortalDefault — Salesforce Customer Portal theme
- Webstore — Salesforce AppExchange theme

hopefully we can use this in Workflows, Validations, Formulas, Apex & Visualforce..

[Official Reference](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring16/release-notes/rn_vf_uitheme.htm)

Comment: Many Thanks Vamsi. I'll select this as the correct answer as there is an API opened up to developers now.

Comment: It is worth being aware that there is a known issue with Salesforce Classic in mobile. The Theme displayed shows as Theme4t rather than Theme3, as would be expected: https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000jl1UQAQ

Answer (score 4):

Until there's an official Salesforce way I'm going with a JS solution to detect if the user is using a mobile device.  I'm using JS to find the user agent and match against the keyword ['Mobi'](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Browser_detection_using_the_user_agent#Mobile.2C_Tablet_or_Desktop):

```
var isMobile = function() {
     //using regex here so developers can add more keywords if needed
     return navigator.userAgent.match('(Mobi)') ? true : false;
}
```

If the user is using a browser on a mobile device, they will be navigated to Salesforce1. Also the User Agent for the Salesforce1 App (Android and iOS) has 'Salesforce**Mobi**leSDK'.

Thanks Vamsi Krishna for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: glad u got it working.. does it cover tablets as well ??

Comment: If the tablet has Mobi in the user agent then yes. You could add 'Tablet' to the regex : '(Mobi|Tablet)' . I found Mobi on its own worked well. Phone's I tested with: Android, iPhone and Windoze. Tablets : Android, iPad and Surface. Everything seemed in sync with what Salesforce is doing (The Surface navigated to Lightning experience and isMobile returned false).

Answer (score 1):

```
 public static string isLightningExperience()
 {
        boolean isLightningExperience = false;
        string id = UserInfo.getUserId();
        for (User u: [SELECT Id, UserPreferencesLightningExperiencePreferred FROM User WHERE Id =: id LIMIT 1])
        {
            isLightningExperience = u.UserPreferencesLightningExperiencePreferred;
        }
        return string.valueOf(isLightningExperience);
 }
```

the value of the field UserPreferencesLightningExperiencePreferred in the object user change when the user interface switch. if UserPreferencesLightningExperiencePreferred is ture => Lightning Desktop , if false => Classic Desktop

Comment: Just putting code will not help. Please explain how this resolves the issue.

Comment: the value of the field UserPreferencesLightningExperiencePreferred in the object user change when the user interface switch. if  UserPreferencesLightningExperiencePreferred  is ture => Lightning Desktop , if false => Classic Desktop

Comment: Please use [edit](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/162578/edit) to update your answer and not put it as a comment