# typeof sforce != 'undefined' doesnot works in detail lightning page

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

i had a component a testComponent.

```
<aura:component>
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}" />
</aura:component>
```

its controller is

```
doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        console.log(typeof sforce != 'undefined');
}
```

when i embed this component in my detail page of contacts. it is given sforce as undefined. i am excepting that in lightning it should return as true.

Comment: `sforce === undefined` would return true is `sforce` is undefinde

Comment: You are writing the code in a lightning component itself. I didn't get the rationale behind checking whether its a lightning page or not. I suppose for this component, typeof sforce will always be true

Comment: @HemantJain this component can be in embeded in visualforce Page to use it in classic.

Comment: Added a answer, see if it helps

Comment: sforce returns true if the device is mobile and false if it is desktop.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `UserContext` variable to check whether the `component` is being used in Salesforce1/Classic/LEX.

Refer the link of a blog [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2016/02/lightning-components-visualforce-lightning.html), which explains the usage and implementation of this.

Another detailed, example of managing the `Visualforce` and `Lightning experience` is [here](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/lex_dev_visualforce/units/lex_dev_visualforce_multipurpose_pages)

Also, [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/95647/how-to-detect-if-a-user-is-in-salesforce1-vs-lightning-desktop) is a similar question answered.

You can use this **Usercontext UI theme value** to detect the type of page.

See if this helps

Comment: actually i have 4-5 levels of components. So i donot want to pass attribute from visualforce down to eacha nd every component. I want to check within component .