# How to Detect Salesforce app is being accessed from a desktop or a sf1 app?

Tags: salesforce1-app, lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps

I need to write  a javascript function ,or any event to detect whether the salesforce app is being accessed from a  desktop or sf1 app
can you help me on this ?

Answer (score 2):

The answer on the post below checks if the user is currently using desktop or salesforce1 within a visualforce page. Hope this fits your requirements.

Here's the post from stackexchange forum:
[Detect if Visualforce Page is in Salesforce1](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/33514/detect-if-visualforce-page-is-in-salesforce1)